# Como passar array javascript para formulário e pegar os valores no php?

Tags: php, array, arraylist

Tenho um formulário que cria uma lista de imagens selecionadas antes de enviar através de um input `type='file'`

No entanto como posso passar o `Array` *JavaScript* para o formulário e submeter ele ao clicar no `action`?

preciso resgatar o array enviado em php no próprio php

```js
var nomess = [];

function handleFileSelect() {
    var output = document.getElementById("resultt");
    arquivos = $("#imagem").prop("files");
    var nomes = $.map(arquivos, function(val) { return val.name; });

    //new
    var filesStr = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < arquivos.length; i++) {
        var extensao = nomes[i].split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if(extensao == "doc" || extensao == "docx"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/word.png";
        }else if(extensao == "jpg" || extensao == "jpeg"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/jpg.png";
        }else if(extensao == "png"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/png.png";
        }else if(extensao == "xml"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/xml.png";
        }else if(extensao == "gif"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/gif.png";
        }else if(extensao == "pdf"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/pdf.png";
        }else if(extensao == "bmp"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/bmp.png";
        }else if(extensao == "txt"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/txt.png";
        }else if(extensao == "xlsx" || extensao == "xls"){
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/xls.png";
        }else{
            icone = "http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/file.png";
        }
        nomess.push(arquivos[i]);
        filesStr += "<li>" + arquivos[i].name + "<button onclick='removeLiy(this)' style='background-color:white; border:0'><i class='fas fa-trash' style='color:red; font-size: 24px; padding: 8px 0px 0px 3px;'></i></button><img src='"+icone+"' height='24' />" + "</li>";
    }

    console.log(nomess);

    document.getElementById("imagem").value = "";
    document.getElementById("resultt").innerHTML += filesStr;

}

function removeLiy(e) {
        nomess = nomess.filter(function(imagem) {
        return imagem.name !== e.parentNode.innerHTML.split("<button")[0];

        console.log(nomess);

    })
    e.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);
    console.log(nomess);

}

document.getElementById('imagem').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, true);
```

```html
<form id="formExemplo" action="nova-acao/salvar'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-toggle="validator" role="form">

    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">

        <input type="file" onchange="handleFileSelect" name="imagem" id="imagem" style="" multiple="multiple">

    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Você quer apenas enviar os valores de input file para a página que recebe o PHP ou quer exatamente passar no js para enviar?

Comment: eu queria pegar o array js e de alguma forma criar  ou povoar um input file, logo após quando eu clicar no enviar ele deveria enviar os outros campos e este com os arrays.

estes arrays são imagens sem restrição de extensão...

Comment: @Eliseu B. você sabe como deve ser feito?

Comment: desculpe a demora, a solução  abaixo atende sua necessidade, se funcionar por favor dê o voto de resposta aceita.

Answer (score 2):

Tratei aqui exclusivamente da tarefa de adicionar um novo input `type="file"` já "populado", como parece que você precisa.

A cada novo arquivo adicionado no input `name="imagem"`, é realizado um clone do mesmo dentro do `<form>` e resetado o valor do input "original".

Você pode conferir rodando aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/emanuelpoletto/doc85uxe/18/

Dá para ocultar o novo input via CSS. Eu só não fiz isso ali para ajudar na didática da resposta. Assim, o comportamento está visível. Espero que ajude.

```js
$('#imagem').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    let form = $('#formExemplo'),
      newFile = $(this).clone(),
      newName = 'imagem' + form.find('[name="imagem"]').length;
    newFile.removeAttr('id')
      .attr('name', newName)
    //.css('display', 'none');
    $('#formExemplo').append(newFile);
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formExemplo" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="imagem" id="imagem" multiple="multiple">
</form>
```

Comment: Ocultar os inputs do clone ok eu consigo tranquilo.

Agora precisaria testar isso para pegar o arquivo para tratamento na outra página , ou seja enviar o arquivo

Comment: Sim, @RichardBarcelos Eu me ative a essa etapa do form + javascript porque foi o código que você compartilhou. Espero que consiga testar o envio dessa forma.

Penso que o tratamento do POST lá no PHP seria um outro tópico. Mas se precisar de ajuda também posso tentar dar uma mão.

Comment: beleza amigo, agradeço. No incio deste poste eu mostro o código java que mostra o nome do anexo, coloquei um botão de deletar e ele deleta o array e as informações como peso do arquivo selecionado, você viu? Ali tbm eu deleto. naquele código minha ideia é passar esse array para o forme ou criar uma session algo que eu possa recuperar no php depois..  com um simples  $rr= $_FILES['nomess'];

Comment: Eu vi o seu print abaixo *(minha pontuação aqui só permite comentar nas minhas próprias perguntas/respostas por enquanto hehe)*

Se você disser que está tudo bem usar um input `type="file"` sem o atributo `multiple` para tratarmos 1 arquivo por vez, eu consigo elaborar mais essa resposta para resolver a sua demanda como um todo.

Comment: Se usarmos o multiple vc acha que não funciona?

Comment: não tem um chat por aqui tbm não? rsrs

Comment: **Usando o multiple:** pode ser que você tenha vários arquivos num mesmo input. Como remover 1 único arquivo do input quando for necessário? Infelizmente, você não tem os caminhos completos dos arquivos (analisando seu print e testando no inspector aqui tbm).

Comment: **NÃO usando o multiple:** você terá um input para cada arquivo. Logo, se quiser remover 1 arquivo, é só remover o input tbm e tá resolvido.

Comment: Entendi o que você disse, mais viu que eu já deleto os arquivos? tipo se eu subo 4 posso deletar somente o segundo.. viu no log que o array 2 seria deletado... você viu?

Comment: o multiple é importante...

Comment: Eu vi que você trata tudo no `array` e teoricamente funcionaria. Só que você não tem como trazer de volta do `array` para o `form` porque o browser não fornece o caminho completo de cada arquivo. A probabilidade é de que o PHP receba só os nomes e não os arquivos propriamente ditos. Esse é o embate da sua abordagem.


Cara, eu posso até fazer uma outra tentativa aqui de resolver **mantendo o multiple**. Mas talvez leve um tempinho... não sei se consigo responder hoje. Farei ASAP.

Comment: ASAP ?  ok :)  aguardo

Comment: @RichardBarcelos elaborei uma nova resposta mais completa que resolveu o upload **com multiple** :) A solução é usar Ajax mesmo para submeter os files. Dá uma olhada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363895/45707

Comment: ok só vi agora, vou verificar e retorno

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

@emanuelpoletto Aqui eu mostro que o array esta com as informações do arquivo.. não?

Comment: quero clicar em incluir ações e enviar os anexos da lista

Answer (score 0):

Os browsers não permitem manipular o FileList de um `input[type=file]`. Podemos manter a sua abordagem, gerando o `array` com os arquivos. Mas não dá para retornar o mesmo `array` posteriormente ao `input[type=file]`, alterando ou mesmo mantendo intacta a lista de arquivos.

A solução é enviar esses arquivos via Ajax. O resto do form pode ser submetido normalmente ou por Ajax também, tanto faz.

Baseado no código da pergunta, elaborei essa resposta que faz precisamente isso:

- capta a lista de arquivos a cada `change` do `input`;
- envia a lista de arquivos via Ajax no `submit` do `form`;
- submete o "resto" do form normalmente depois de ter subido os arquivos.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('formExemplo'),
    formSubmit = false,
    files = [],
    filesSentOk = 0,
    filesSentError = 0;

document.getElementById('imagem').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  let output = document.getElementById('result');

  for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    let name = this.files[i].name,
        ext  = name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase(),
        icon = 'http://www.programari.com.br/assets/images/icons/';

    switch (ext) {
      case 'jpg'  :
      case 'png'  :
      case 'xml'  :
      case 'gif'  :
      case 'pdf'  :
      case 'bmp'  :
      case 'txt'  :
      case 'xls'  : icon += ext; break;
      case 'doc'  :
      case 'docx' : icon += 'word'; break;
      case 'jpeg' : icon += 'jpg'; break;
      case 'xlsx' : icon += 'xls'; break;
      default     : icon += 'file';
    }
    icon += '.png';

    files.push(this.files[i]);
    output.innerHTML += '<li>' + name + '<button onclick="removeLiy(this)" style="background-color:white; border:0"><i class="fas fa-trash" style="color:red; font-size: 24px; padding: 8px 0px 0px 3px;"></i></button><img src="' + icon + '" height="24" /></li>';
  }

  this.value = '';
});

function removeLiy(el) {
  let index = Array.from(el.parentNode.children).indexOf(el);

  files.splice(index, 1);
  el.parentNode.remove();
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  if (formSubmit) {
    return;
  }

  event.preventDefault();

  files.forEach(function(file) {
    sendFile(file);
  });

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if ((filesSentOk + filesSentError) >= files.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      if (filesSentError <= 0) {
        formSubmit = true;
        form.submit();
      } else {
        alert('Erro ao enviar arquivo(s). Confira o console log.');
      }
    }
  }, 500);

  return false;
});

function sendFile(file) {
  let formData = new FormData(),
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      let states = [
        'request not initialized',
        'server connection established',
        'request received',
        'processing request',
        'request finished and response is ready'
      ];
      console.log('File: ' + file.name + '; State: ' + this.readyState + ' (' + states[this.readyState] + '); Status: ' + this.status + ' (' + this.statusText + ')' );
      if (this.readyState == 4) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
          filesSentOk++;
        } else {
          filesSentError++;
        }
      }
      // console.log('Response: ' + this.responseText);
    // }
  };

  formData.set('imagem', file);
  request.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'));
  request.send(formData);
};
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="formExemplo" action="http://example.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        Input de texto para teste: <input type="text" name="campo_qualquer_para_teste" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">
        <br><br>
        <input type="file" name="imagem" id="imagem" multiple="multiple">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </div>
</form>
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

IMPORTANTE: não está contido aí algum tipo de validação, seja no front ou no back-end. Por exemplo, se o Ajax retornar que a requisição foi enviada com sucesso e obteve HTTP status 200 do server não significa necessariamente que o upload foi bem sucedido. O ideal é incrementar as devidas validações antes de rodar em produção :)

Comment: Legal depois incrementar algo visual que sinalize "loading" para o usuário ao clicar no submit para ele saber o que está acontecendo enquanto os files estão subindo. Dá até pra sinalizar os files de um em um, à medida em que vão subindo. O upload via Ajax está rodando assíncrono ali, então os files vão subir em paralelo e consequentemente mais rápido ;)

Comment: Com este formato eu envio os outros campos do form separadamente? neste caso eu gravo os anexos e depois os outros campos?

Comment: Exato. Nessa abordagem, no submit do form ele envia os arquivos (de um em um) e por último envia todo o resto do form, tudo em sequência, num único clique. Vc só tem que tratar isso no back-end. O número de requisições que o PHP vai receber depende da quantidade de arquivos adicionados ;)